# Using android alarmclock

Tags: android, android-alarms

Is it possible to use the `com.android.alarmclock` so that I can use it to kick off alarm features in my application?  If it is how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

Since API level 9 you can set the [AlarmClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html) by creating an intent like the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "New Alarm");
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hours);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, mins);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

The service you need is the [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: AlarmManager doesn't handle alarm clock features... "These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future."

Answer (score 0):

No the AlarmManager is not going to set off a Alarm!